# 'keras_retinanet' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to  setting up a Keras RetinaNet using jupyter notebook in local-machine below is the github link.
 https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet

I am facing issue with below command

```
!keras_retinanet/bin/train.py --freeze-backbone --random-transform --batch-size 20 --steps 100 --epochs 2 csv annotations.csv classes.csv
```

I am using Anaconda I tried below cmd also

```
pip install keras-retinanet
```

**Expected output**

Using TensorFlow backend.
2019-05-16 07:09:08.796839: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2300000000 Hz

Comment: try ```python keras_retinanet/bin/train.py --freeze-backbone --random-transform --batch-size 20 --steps 100 --epochs 2 csv annotations.csv classes.csv```

Comment: I think in jupyter notbook python is not required. Even I tried I got the same result

Comment: Based on my experience, train retinanet should be performed inside of a console.

Comment: I tried what ever you said but I got invalid error

Comment: Can you post the exact error message?

Comment: Right now I don't have error message I tried to setup github code  https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet. Thank for your help

Answer (score 0):

This might have come late, but for any other person who might be interested, the error is becouse *keras_retinanet* is not on your system path.
How to fix the issue:

- Clone https://github.com/fizyr/keras-retinanet.
- from, the keras_retinanet, find the bin folder and copy its path.
- Edit your system environment variables by pasting the path to your bin.